# Why does Newtonian gravity imply that gravitational potential energy is negative?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, conventions

Why can't the zero value of gravitational potential energy be set at a different point instead of infinite distance?

I quoted it from: https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Guth/Guth3.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the gravitational potential energy at infinity is zero?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/509054/)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17082/2451 and links therein.